# EC2 instance access and change SSH keypairs replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

1. Is there some quick, automatic (i.e. through some script) and safe way to change an EC2 keypair in AWS (besides entering in each instance and changing it manually the authorized keys)?
2. What is the best practice in terms of EC2 instances access to avoid changing all the keypairs everytime an employee is leaving? Should each IAM user create his own keypair to access the instances (and when he leaves just disable the user)? Should I create a user (and not using the ec2-user default user) + a keypair on each instance he needs to access?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I believe that good idea to assign to each employee own ssh key pair. What about keypair managment you can upload own ssh keys or create personal users on ec2 instances, however there is not outbox solution provided by aws. That why you have to create own solution for this, for example with help of chef manage personal users and key pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate separate ssh keys for each employee and name accordingly. 
Something like id_rsa_eployee_name.

So when the employee leaves, removing the key from authorized section will work. When you launch an instance in aws and select a EC2 keypair, you cannot change it once the instance has started running. All ssh,scp or other operations to that instance should be authenticated with that key.